# How to change a website domain name on Netlify which is using Cecil?

Tags: netlify, netlify-cms, hyde

I have deployed a website on Netlify from here: https://the-butler.cecil.app/about/
When I changed the subdomain, the website lost all formatting and became a plain HTML.
After inspecting the website I found that there were multiple instances where the previous domain is mentioned which obviously does not exist now.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your sourcecode to update those instances that mention the previous domain, to look at the new domain, or ideally to be a [relative url](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_href.asp), as then it will always look at the current site.

I suspect that the reason it looks like plain HTML is that you have lost access to your CSS stylesheets, so look into updating those links first.